# Minimize a combined window group in the taskbar with a single click

Tags: taskbar, windows-11

In windows 7 and 10 I could shift+right click a window group, and then I'd have a "Minimize All" option.
I can't find this in Windows 11.

Is there a way to achieve this?
If not built-in, is there some tool that could help with that?

[image: Combined window group]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 11, This functionality is present now (I'm running Windows 11 Pro v22H2). If you hover over the icon of one of the apps in the group, you'll see both the app itself and the app group pop-up. You can then right click on the app group, and there's the option to minimize/restore the group.

[image: Screenshot]